# CSS Rendering in react is different than in static web

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a react app that based on a static website. Afterwards, I took a little bit different kind of css rendering between them. e.g:

*on the static website:*
[image]

```
<html>
<body>
  ...
  <div class="title">
    <div class="left">
      <h2>What's</h2>
      <h3>Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="white-lines"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum ... </p>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

*on the react app:*
[image]

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import '../style/index.css'

function Home() {
  return (
    <> 
    ...
    <div className="title">
        <div className="left">
          <h2>What's</h2>
          <h3>Lorem Ipsum ? </h3>
        </div>
        <div className="right">
          <div className="white-lines"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum ... </p>
    ...
    </>
  )
}
```

I had already make sure that both is using the same CSS style, it looks like (complete css file you can access [here](https://pastebin.com/UWhQSPG7)):

```
.about .title {
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 50px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

When both are inspected with browser devtools, here is the comparison:
[image]
[image]

Is there a mistake about importing css or any other?I want to make that in react app will looks like at a static website

Comment: Do you see any difference in the style when you inspect the elements using the browser's dev tools? I don't think there's enough info in the question to know what's going on, there's probably some other style getting applied (maybe a height/max-height?)

Comment: Please share your CSS too

Comment: I had already edited my post for the additional information

Comment: Have a look at the "Computed" tab next to "Styles" in the dev tools. It will show you the final result of all your CSS and can be compared between the working/failing versions.

Comment: Can you share what the Header component is doing?